# jquery keyup events please help me

Tags: jquery, keyboard, keypress, keyup

hello  I have  an  problem  in  my code 
when  i  click left word "ahmed" go to left  5 px 
when clicking again  5 px extra  the problem is 
i need to click  left in  keyboard word move and  continue moving 
until i  let the  key 
by the way  imagine  number  10 in  web site 
 i want to increase the 10 by  clicking  down when continue clicking 
the value will decrease

enter here and see my  problem 
http://masry.host56.com/moving_object/index.php

Comment: please post relevant code here, many folks here are still using 56k connection network

Comment: I assume that once you get an answer, you're going to fix the problem...making a link to the current content useless in the future.  It'd be better if the relevant code were included in the question -- or at the very least, if you created and linked to a demo on a site like http://ideone.com or http://jsfiddle.net, so the code that demonstrates the issue can be seen after you've fixed it on your site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you're , I've been working on this fiddle for you:

```
<p id="move" style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;">test</p>
```

JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
var element = $( "#move" )
, doc = $( document )
, Motion
, goRight = function(){
   element.css( "left" ,1+ parseInt(element.css( "left")));
   if ( Motion === goRight ) {
      setTimeout( goRight , 10 );
   }
}
goUp = function(){
   element.css( "top" , parseInt(element.css( "top")) -1);
   if ( Motion === goUp ) {
      setTimeout( goUp , 10 );
   }
}
goDown = function(){
   element.css( "top" ,1+ parseInt(element.css( "top")));
   if ( Motion === goDown ) {
      setTimeout( goDown , 10 );
   }
}
goleft = function(){
   element.css( "left" ,parseInt(element.css( "left"))-1);
   if ( Motion === goleft ) {
      setTimeout( goleft , 10 );
   }
};

doc.keydown( function( e ) {
   if ( e.which === 39 && Motion !== goRight ) {
      Motion = goRight;
      goRight();
   }
    else if( e.which === 38 && Motion !== goUp){
      Motion = goUp;
      goUp();
    }
     else if( e.which === 37 && Motion !== goleft){
      Motion = goleft;
      goleft();
    }
        else if( e.which ===40 && Motion !== goDown){
      Motion = goDown;
      goDown();
    }

} );

doc.keyup( function () {

   Motion = null;
} );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Imadbakir/5yShL/22/

Comment: thanks but can  get me  code in all dirs
left,right,down,and up

Comment: look when go left  dotted blue line appeare 
test it  here  http://jsfiddle.net/Imadbakir/5yShL/22/ and here http://masry.host56.com/moving_object/index.php